# Nesting HTML Pages using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I'm trying to create a toggle between two tables. I have a button that when you click will change a search parameter in the URL using `$location.search`. I have each of the tables saved in separate HTML files.

I was wondering if it is possible to use createElement('div') to insert an HTML file into another one (I was thinking through a directive in the angular module). If that isn't possible, then how would I insert an HTML file into another HTML file from the module?

Thanks!

Comment: You will want to use jquery (or jquery lite) to do this. Yes encapsulating this in a directive will be a good idea.

Comment: are you using uirouter or ngroute?

Comment: I have tried using ngroute but you can't really route by a search query parameter

Comment: As @PavanAsTechie suggested. Just give a look to ui-router. It is a powerfull routing solution that can give you a way to define states and nested view. http://www.funnyant.com/angularjs-ui-router/

Comment: @Sam how would you suggest doing this with jquery?

Comment: and thanks, @Okazari, I'll take a look. I just need to be able to route by search query, this was my attempt at a workaround

Comment: If you actually can add you two tables, you also could have use ng-show with a boolean. ng-show="table1" on your HTML for table1 and ng-show="!table1" for the table2. On you switch add ng-click="table1 = !table1" and this could do the work. I'll give you an answer with this working on plunker and the ui-router as an advice

Answer (score 5):

As it were suggested you should give a look at ui-router and define a nested view depending on the url parameter.

If you don't need a complete router you could do this using ng-show in angular.

Here is a [plunker as exemple](http://plnkr.co/edit/fmSSbLbLjVpkg0VQ7BeR?p=preview)

I added on each table the ng-show attribute :

```
 ng-show="!switchTable" for table1
 ng-show="switchTable" for table2
```

And i added this ng-click on the button :

```
 ng-click="switchTable = !switchTable
```

Comment: Thanks, that's how I first built it and it worked like a charm but now I need to incorporate the table name as a search query into the URL

Comment: @EvanBennewies If you have some trouble using ui-router, feel free to ask, since this didn't answer your issue.